# How do I set the request timeout for one controller action in an asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to increase the request timeout for a specific controller action in my application. I know I can do it in the web.config for the entire application, but I'd rather change it on just this one action.

Web.config example:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" /> 
</system.web>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC and httpRuntime executionTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492346/asp-net-mvc-and-httpruntime-executiontimeout)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can set this programmatically in the controller:-

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
```

Sets the timeout to 5 minutes instead of the default 110 seconds (what an odd default?)

Comment: With the advent of the AsyncController it's worth remembering that to get a similar effect for asynchronous requests you should use the [AsyncTimeout] property.

Comment: My question with this answer is how would it truly only affect the one action in which it was placed in?  So after the request is done does that setting get put back for all future requests?

Comment: @jhilden HttpContext is instantiated on a per request basis, so it would be back to the default value on the next request

Comment: You might wanna add HttpContext.Current ('Current' is missing)

Comment: I get: "httpcontext does not contain a definition for current". I'm using .NET Core 2.0. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @JedatKinports: try changing the case of your current to upper case "Current". I know this is quite old.

Comment: @Tadej, I inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and use that, but `Server` does not seem to be a property on it anymore.

Comment: how if aspnet core api sir?

Answer (score 80):

```
<location path="ControllerName/ActionName">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Probably it is better to set such values in web.config instead of controller. Hardcoding of configurable options is considered harmful.

Comment: -1 Hard coding is okay for special circumstances as the OP described. It sounds like a specific action needs a different timeout than the rest of the actions so hard coding inside the action sounds like a good place.

Comment: executionTimeout does not work for MVC - this is the wrong answer.
see here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1715081/4723882.aspx?Re+web+config+executionTimeout+not+working+in+ASP+NET+MVC

Comment: please note this is ignored completed if debug mode is on

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

executionTimeout

Optional Int32 attribute.

Specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.

This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False. Therefore, if the debug attribute is True, you do not have to set this attribute to a large value in order to avoid application shutdown while you are debugging.

Comment: This is not the most correct answer, because it has the side effect of changing the execution timeout for all other controller actions as well.

Comment: @EricJ. only within the Controller Route(s) that start with `ControllerName\ActionName`

Comment: I would argue that this answer is the Hard-Coding.  You can't change a Web.Config dynamically in the middle of running a system.  Whereas ActionFilters or similar Attributes can access dynamic information, including configuration databases, to make the timeout dynamic.

Answer (score 24):

I had to add "Current" using .NET 4.5:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
```