# web api apicontroller timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the request timeout for one controller action in an asp.net mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579523/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app)

I have an apicontroller class for .net's web api (.net 4)

I would like to set the timeout for RESPONSE for the controller (not a global timeout)

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I have the same problem. An MVC 4 ApiController is not the same MVC Controller they were talking about in 2009. The answers to the other question do not help at all.

Comment: He is right about it not being a duplicate? Anyone?

Comment: Not a duplicate! ApiController != MvcController