# ASP.NET Web API not timing out requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm having an issue with ASP.NET Web API not timing out requests.  I've tried multiple solutions mentioned for ASP.NET MVC4 but to no avail.

Solutions tried include:

- Set ExecutionTimeout property in web.config & set debug=false
- Programmatically set the ScriptTimeout property & set debug=false
- Set the AsyncTimeout attribute and cancellation token in an async endpoint method

I'm at a loss here because it looks like we can not get ASP.NET Web API to timeout any requests.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the request timeout for one controller action in an asp.net mvc application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579523/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app)

Comment: Hey @Fals it's not a duplicate because the link you provided is for ASP.NET MVC 4 not ASP.NET Web API and the solutions provided do not work for ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: we currently have a bug tracking this : http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/858

Comment: Kiran, just to confirm there is no way to timeout an ASP.net Web API request currently?  In version 5.1 we can use async methods and a cancellation token.  Is there any work around to this now?

Comment: I know this is late, but is there anyway to do this now? I'm using Web API2 and I'm also inquisitive about how to force cancel an action method.