# Set form post timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that upload a file and the server has to process a large operation that takes several minutes.

My code:

**.cshtml:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post,
            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Process a large operation here.

    return View();
}
```

I know it's possible to do it with [web.config configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/579599/1233788) and with [server code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/579599/1233788).
My question: Is it possible to do with client side configuration?

I ask that because when using `XMLHttpRequest` like `jQuery.ajax` its possible to set the timeout, so is it possible to do in html form tag or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the request timeout for one controller action in an asp.net mvc application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579523/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app)

Comment: I update the question. This duplication it's not available anymore.

Comment: Why is it so important to set it from within your view code? Why can't you modify the controller code?

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is to create AsyncController and then you can set [[AsyncTimeout(xxxx)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynctimeoutattribute.aspx)] or [[NoAsyncTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.noasynctimeoutattribute.aspx)] attributes in your action.

[Here is an example on how to do it](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2011/12/07/Set-the-AsyncTimeout-attribute-for-your-async-controllers.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying something with client configuration as jQuery.ajax. +1.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi then you might consider to use jQuery.ajax from your view where you can specify timeout. But I would recommend to use AsyncController