# Entity Framework Code First - Maintain a Long connection to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Below is my Code to Query a 24 Column database using linq

```
  var list = (from x in db.graph_update
              where x.serial == serial_number 
                    && (x.plotdate >= date_from && x.plotdate <= date_to)
              select new {
                  x.plotdate,
                  x.Temperature
              }).ToList();
```

Because the Database contains a large amounts to data, the connection time to grab all this data will take a long time and usually results in an error:

> > 500 - The request timed out.
>
> The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

How do I maintain this long running connection so it wouldn't timeout and be able to grab all of the data?

Comment: Little bit off topic but if you run the SQL version of that code in SSMS, does it also take a long time to get the results?

Comment: @JohanP Hi, yes I have and yes it does, It took around 10 minutes to get all of the result.

Comment: You're going to have to set `Connection Timeout` property for EF as well as set the [request timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579523/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app) for your  web API

Comment: You might want to profile that query to see if you need to add some indexes to improve it.  Also if it's retrieving a lot of data you might want to think about why you need so much data for a web call.

Comment: Generally long running queries and large data sets should use a pattern that involves the web api queing a job to be handled by a background process, potentially on a seperate machine from the web service, and the web api immediately returning the caller a URL to poll for completion.  The caller can either poll once a minute to check for completion, or let the caller register a URL that you will notify of completion.  For large datasets, instead of transfering the file through the webapi, you'd drop it in a location and provide caller the URL for direct download.

Comment: @AaronLS are you referring Thread and Thread Pooling?

Comment: That would be one option, or you could insert a record into table representing the parameters for the request, and have a separate application running as a windows service polling the table and running any jobs. There's alot of options for doing these kinds of jobs.

Comment: @AaronLS Thanks for the suggestions, could you please provide me a link to an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason your query takes that long you can profile it and get max query time and just set timeout:

**Entity Framework 6:**

```
this.context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

**Entity Framework 5:**

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
```