# Increase executionTimeout of MVC Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to increase executionTimeout of a controller Method. Options i tried so far :

1. Web.config
   [image]

<location path="Components/FileUploadExplorer/Controllers/FileUpload/ChunkSave"
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="12000" maxRequestLength="100000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1024"/
</system.web>

2. Wanted to try this but not able to Find Current property in the controller. Using .Net 4.5

   HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
3. Cant change Timeout in Application_BeginRequest as it will change for all the pages.

Any help is appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

[How do I set the request timeout for one controller action in an asp.net mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579523/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app)

You can set this programmatically in the controller:-

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
```

Sets the timeout to 5 minutes instead of the default 110 seconds (what an odd default?)

Comment: See my point No 2 above i tried this but Current property is not recognized. So i tried using HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300; but looks like it does not work. I tried setting this as first line in the Actionmethod of the controller.

Comment: I will update my answer.  Using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout works for me.

Comment: Have u seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474309/timeouts-with-long-running-asp-net-mvc-core-controller-httppost-method ?