# How to increase time-out error time span of Rest web API in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

My **Web API** Already published.
One of our application specification is upload an image (there are 3 images can uploaded). From the front end we already compressed the image from (at least) **3 MB** into **500 KB**. and there is no issue with that and when post or get data just need 1,2 - 1,3 seconds.

From frontend we are using **BASE64**.

But Our User request to us some Enhancement where they need to upload an image (without size & Resolution compressing) with original size, where the size of an one image is **3MB** (at least).
we have tried with existing **Web API** and there is a major issue occur, which is our application cannot post the data into backend.

My assumption is there need a long time to upload a large image and then the connection timed out.

If the my assumption is right, so please help me, How to increase the time out when large images are uploaded ?

I had tried to use form-data, but still take long time to upload the large images.

this my JSON. Sorry, I can just upload image.. cause limit characters in stackoverflow that can post.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context and code? Does it work with a 500kb file but not a 3mb file? What code is getting the timeout errors? Do you uploado one file or both?

Comment: My guess is your front end is throwing the timeout so you will need to adjust the timeout there. There is also this but idk what you are using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579523/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app

Comment: @NavidM.. thanks, For your help, its maybe can reduce the risk of Time-out. But I Think transaction will be took a long time because the package data is big.

Comment: @TallesSantana.. ok i will edit my post