# file size upload limitation in ASP.NET MVC: more than 1 maxRequestLength setting in web.config(s)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, web-config, maxrequestlength

I'd like to have more than 1 setting for maxRequestLength - file size upload limitation (e.g. one for File/New, other for Picture/New). All of my Actions take additional parameters (e.g. /File/New?folderId=234).

Single setting works as expected:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" maxRequestLength="1024" />
```

I tried to have 2 settings with 2 location sections in the root web.config, but without any success. I'm not sure what to write in "path" - physical aspx page of a view, or controller+action... however, nothing seems to work.

```
<location path="/File/">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" maxRequestLength="4096" />
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="/Picture/">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" maxRequestLength="1024" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I tried to put another web.config in a specific view folder (e.g. /Views/Picture/...), like it works in classic Webform ASP.NET, but this doesn't seem to do the trick either...

```
<location path="">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" maxRequestLength="1024" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

No matter what I do, only one value for httpRuntime.maxRequestLength is applied - that in (root) web.config...system.web.

Comment: See my answer here: [ASP.NET MVC and httpRuntime executionTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492346/asp-net-mvc-and-httpruntime-executiontimeout/636609#636609)

Answer (score 11):

I believe the Path attribute shouldn't start or end with a "/" - so you should have:

```
<location path="File">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" maxRequestLength="4096" />
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Picture">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" maxRequestLength="1024" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Your virtual or physical directory–level Web.config's shouldn't have the <location> elements.

That should sort you out.

The docs for the [Location element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) even have this very example:

> The following code example demonstrates how to set the uploaded file size limit to 128 KB for only the page specified.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="UploadPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="128"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are right, of course. I tried every possible variation ("Picture", "/Picture", "Picture/", "/Picture/", "Views/Picture" etc.), but when posting my question I chose "/Picture/", which was obviously wrong. However, it didn't work for some other reason. I refactored the code (changed the way the parameters were supplied - now as querystring parameters) and it started to work properly, but I'm not quite sure what the problem was. :-( Thanks anyway! :-)