# executionTimeout not working on asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried set the executionTimeout in web.config for an asp.net mvc application.

```
<location path="Home/Index">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime  executionTimeout="5"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

any used the `Thread.Sleep` in Index action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Thread.Sleep(30000);            
    return View();
}
```

also, **i set complilation's debug to "false"**.
after the action sleep about 30 seconds and the "request timeout" exception not throws out and the view had been rendered successfully.

any one know how to make the executionTimeout to work in asp.net mvc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC and httpRuntime executionTimeout ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492346/asp-net-mvc-and-httpruntime-executiontimeout)

Comment: i tried this solution and it work fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474157/executiontimeout-in-asp-net-mvc-solved

Answer (score 12):

You need to fulfill the following:

1. Domain name is not localhost (to test timeout you should use "YourComputerName" instead of "localhost").
2. Project is compiled in Release mode.
3. `<compilation debug="false">`

Then also, think about this:

Internally ASP.NET uses a Timer to invoke the request cancelation process. This timer is fired once every 15 seconds, so if the `executionTimeout` is set to 3 seconds, in reality the request can timeout at any time between 3 seconds and 18 seconds.

When the timer is fired, a thread from the ThreadPool is used to check all the requests. The ones that have timed out are sent a `ThreadAbortException` by calling Abort on the thread executing the request.

Note: Keep in mind that `ThreadAbortException` can only be observed by managed code. So if you thread is calling some unmanaged functions, the thread will not be aborted, and therefore the timeout will not be enforced, until the execution returns to the managed world. That can be an arbitrary length of delay depending on what those unmanaged code does.

Read more: http://consultantpoint.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/how-the-execution-timeout-is-managed-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 1):

If you have your web.config set to debug="true" it will ignore the value you set:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx