# httpRuntime attribute doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, timeout

I have created fresh new asp.net mvc 3 project. Then I added the following strings in the `Web.config` file:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="1"/>
```

And the following instruction in the `Index` action:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

After sleeping for 30 sec I can see index view. Why is `httpRuntime` attribute not working? I created a new test project because I can't achieve break by timeout in my working project. My working project is running on iis and the Test project on iis express.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I tried all stuff from this answer with no luck https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886618/290082

Answer (score 2):

The <httpRuntime executionTimeout> property does not apply to asynchronous frameworks like ASP.NET MVC.  Instead, cooperative cancellation mechanisms like CancellationToken should be used.  Here's an example:

```
[AsyncTimeout(30000 /* 30 seconds */)]
public ActionResult YourMethod(..., CancellationToken token) {
  // perform some long-running work
  while (StillNeedToPerformWork()) {
    DoSomeWork();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }
  return ...;
}
```

I believe the above example requires **MVC 4** or later.  The MVC framework will automatically read the [AsyncTimeout] attribute and provide a proper CancellationToken instance as a parameter to your action method.

For more information on how to consume a CancellationToken from your code, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Also see my Async MVC article,•Using a Cancellation Token section http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CancelToken

Comment: what if you don't provide cancellation token?  I want to apply this globally on all my controllers.  Does it have a global default setting?