# Increase maxRequestLength for MVC Controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can I increase maxRequestLength of ASP.NET request for MVC Controller Action?

I have an MVC controller that accepts file and it can be very large. I increased maxRequestLength in web.config, but it is security issue and the best solution for me will be have increased request length only for Upload method. Is it possible?

I tried

```
<location path="UploadFile">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But it didn't helped

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I increase maxRequestLength of ASP.NET request for MVC Controller Action?

AFAIK, no. But you could use a generic HTTP handler instead of a controller action and then your `<location path="UploadFile"`> will work. For example your handler could be placed in `~/UploadFile/upload.ashx`.

Comment: What about setting <location path="Controller/Action"> from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492346/asp-net-mvc-and-httpruntime-executiontimeout/636609#636609 ? Does it only work for executionTimeout and not for maxRequestLength ?