# How to set execution timeout for 1 second in asp.net web api application

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, timeout, execution-time

How to set execution timeout for 1 second in asp.net web api application.

I set it on web.config file. and also set it on the IIS server. but it doesn't show me the time out error. what is the process to get the timeout error ??

Answer (score 0):

Change the value for httpRuntime executionTimeout in Web.Config. Default is 110 seconds.

`<httpRuntime  executionTimeout = "1" />`

Comment: i did this already. but when i send a request it loads, but no time out error occur.

Comment: try setting it 30 seconds.

Comment: Please look at the very first answer in the link below, you will get your answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901388/difference-between-executiontimeout-and-server-scripttimeout