# Is It possible that heavy query caused to stopped running subsequent code in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a query in my `Asp.net` project, which create two table and then insert amount of date into it, when there are afew data so there is no problem, it is my query :

```
    protected void btnLottryInformationSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int rowCount;
            var finalTempTableName = FindTableName();

            var selecterServicesList = cblServices.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).ToList();
            var selectedServices = selecterServicesList.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, service) => current + ("'" + service.Value + "',")).TrimEnd(',');

            var tempTableName = "Temp_" + finalTempTableName;

            var drawQuery = " if (OBJECT_ID('Temp.dbo." + tempTableName + "') is not null) \ndrop table Temp.dbo." + tempTableName + ";\n";
            drawQuery += " create table Temp.dbo." + tempTableName + "(Number char(11) primary key,RepCount int);\n";
            drawQuery += " if (OBJECT_ID('Temp.dbo." + finalTempTableName + "') is not null) \ndrop table Temp.dbo." + finalTempTableName + ";\n";
            drawQuery += " create table Temp.dbo." + finalTempTableName + "(Id int identity(1,1) primary key,Number char(11));\n";

            drawQuery += " select org.orig \n" +
                         "   into #MoOrig \n" +
                         "    from VSReceiveSend.dbo.OrigPrices org  \n" +
                         "          INNER JOIN VSReceiveSend.dbo.Services     s on (s.Orig   = org.Orig) \n" +
                         " where s.Code in (" + selectedServices + ") and org.MTPrice <> 0  \n ";

            if (drpLotteryType.SelectedValue == "1" || drpLotteryType.SelectedValue == "2")
            {
                drawQuery += " INSERT INTO Temp.dbo." + tempTableName + " (Number,RepCount)\n" +
                             " select number," + (drpLotteryType.SelectedValue == "1" ? "1" : "sum(c) ") +
                             " from (\n" +
                             "     SELECT Number,COUNT(*) c \n" +
                             "     FROM  VSReceiveSend.dbo.ReceivedSMS with(nolock)\n" +
                             "            INNER JOIN VSReceiveSend.dbo.#MoOrig org ON (org.Orig = ReceivedSMS.Orig) \n " +
                             "     WHERE  Date BETWEEN '" + dtpStartDate.Text + "' AND '" + dtpEndDate.Text + "' \n" +
                             "     GROUP BY Number\n" +
                             "     union all \n " +
                             "     SELECT Number,COUNT(*) c \n" +
                             "     FROM  VSReceiveSend.dbo.SentSMS with(nolock) \n" +
                             "            INNER JOIN VSReceiveSend.dbo.OrigPrices org ON (org.Orig = SentSMS.Orig AND org.MTPrice <> 0 ) \n " +
                             "     WHERE  SentDate BETWEEN '" + dtpStartDate.Text + "' AND '" + dtpEndDate.Text + "' AND SentSMS.ServiceCode in (" + selectedServices + ") \n" +
                             "     GROUP BY Number \n" +
                             " ) DerivedTable \n" +
                             " group by number \n" +
                             ((drpLotteryType.SelectedValue == "2" && txtMinAnswerCount.Text != "") ? "HAVING sum(c) >= " + txtMinAnswerCount.Text : "") + ";\n";
            }
            else if (drpLotteryType.SelectedValue == "3")
            {
                var pointCount = int.Parse(txtMinCustomerPoint.Text);

                drawQuery += " INSERT INTO Temp.dbo." + tempTableName + " ( Number,RepCount)\n" +
                             "                                            SELECT Number,SUM(Point) / " + txtDivPoints.Text + " RepCount " +
                             "                                    FROM VsReceiveSend.dbo.SubscriberMatchHistory with(nolock) \n" +
                             "                                where ServiceCode in (" + selectedServices + ") and SUBSTRING(DateTime,1,10)  BETWEEN '" + dtpStartDate.Text + "' AND '" + dtpEndDate.Text + "' \n" +
                             "                                GROUP BY Number\n" +
                             " HAVING SUM(Point) >= " + pointCount + ";\n";
            }

            drawQuery += " with DrawInfo (Number,RepCount) as \n" +
                         "(   select Number,1 \n" +
                         "    from temp.dbo." + tempTableName + "\n" +
                         "       union all \n" +
                         "    select DrawInfo.Number,DrawInfo.RepCount + 1 \n" +
                         "        from Temp.dbo." + tempTableName + "\n" +
                         "    inner join DrawInfo on (DrawInfo.Number = Temp.dbo." + tempTableName + ".Number and DrawInfo.RepCount + 1 <= " + tempTableName + ".RepCount) \n" +
                         ")\n" +
                         " Insert into Temp.dbo." + finalTempTableName + "(Number) \n" +
                         " select DrawInfo.Number \n" +
                         " from DrawInfo";
            if (!checkBoxOrderInformation.Checked)
                drawQuery += " ORDER BY ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) \n";
            else
                drawQuery += " ORDER BY Number \n";

            drawQuery += " option (maxrecursion 0);\n " +
                         " select count(*) from Temp.dbo." + finalTempTableName;


            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VasunReportConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand(drawQuery, connection) { CommandTimeout = 999999999 };
                connection.Open();
                drawFieldSet.Visible = true;
                rowCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                txtNumberOfRow.Text = rowCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            using (var dbs = new ReceiveSendEntitiesV5())
            {
                var matchDrawHistories = new MatchDrawHistory()
                {
                    DrawStartDate = dtpStartDate.Text,
                    DrawEndDate = dtpEndDate.Text,
                    DrawTime = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString(),
                    RowNumber = rowCount,
                    ServiceCode = cblServices.SelectedValue,
                    TableName = finalTempTableName
                };
                dbs.MatchDrawHistories.Add(matchDrawHistories);
                dbs.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "Exception :" + exp.Message;
        }
    }
```

but when there were a lot of data, my code execute until : `txtNumberOfRow.Text = rowCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

so these codes does not execute :

```
 using (var dbs = new ReceiveSendEntitiesV5())
        {
            var matchDrawHistories = new MatchDrawHistory()
            {
                DrawStartDate = dtpStartDate.Text,
                DrawEndDate = dtpEndDate.Text,
                DrawTime = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString(),
                RowNumber = rowCount,
                ServiceCode = cblServices.SelectedValue,
                TableName = finalTempTableName
            };
            dbs.MatchDrawHistories.Add(matchDrawHistories);
            dbs.SaveChanges();
        }
```

how it is possible!!! what is the problem???

Comment: Your string manipulation is strange. Use @ prefix, `string.Format` and `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: It seems you are having timeout issue. Is there any exception?

Comment: Try to run the generated command in SQL Management Studio. Did you try to debug your c# code?

Comment: My code work properly,, when i draw lottery from a a few record amount about 800.000 my code completely execute , but when amount of record were about 25,000,000 my code execute until:    txtNumberOfRow.Text = rowCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), and it doesn't give me execption!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @VDohnal i do it and it works properly!

Comment: Your problem might be connected with the fact that it is ASP.NET app and there are page load timeouts, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108678/increase-asp-net-timeout-on-a-per-page-level