# ASP.NET dynamically set timeout for current request?

Tags: asp.net

We have multi-tenant web app that our customers can extend on server by writing scripts. We want to limit web requests allowed execution time dynamically per tenant so one tenant cannot hurt others performance.

Allowed execution limit could depend on currently executing app action (front end, batch process...) and tenant pricing option (basic/premium...).

E.g. if we could do this in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // GetTimeoutForCurrentRequest contains our business logic
       HttpContext.Current.Request.TimeOut = GetTimeoutForCurrentRequest();
}
```

All I wound by now are solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108678/increase-asp-net-timeout-on-a-per-page-level) that set limit statically for whole site of per url which don't workout for my case.